# Does the magnetic field at a fixed point in space, caused by a charged particle moving at constant speed change as the charged particle moves past it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, charge

And if it does, does that mean that an electromagnetic wave is being generated at that point? Since both the electric field and the magnetic field are changing?

Comment: Yes it change. No it does not means it is being generated there, it means that the "pertubation" on the electromagnetic wave has reached this point. Electric field and magnetic field in waves are always oscilating, if this is what you mean by changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric and magnetic fields changing does not necessarily mean that an electromagnetic wave is produced.

So the electric and magnetic field do change  when a charge moving at a constant velocity passes by a fixed point in space but it does not produce an electromagnetic wave as explained in the answers to the question, [Why doesn't a charged particle moving with constant velocity produce electromagnetic waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428922/why-doesnt-a-charged-particle-moving-with-constant-velocity-produce-electromagn)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the reasoning behind the answers given in the thread you provided me with. But that also raises the question that if I am moving with exact same amount of acceleration and copying the exact movement of the charged particle, then I will observe a stationary charge too. I can then use the same reasoning in the the answers of the link you provided, to say that the charge doesn't produce an electromagnetic wave, Can I not?

Comment: [Will accelerated observer see radiation from the charge that is at rest in observer's frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257927/will-accelerated-observer-see-radiation-from-the-charge-that-is-at-rest-in-obser)